# File Not Being Created in Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, file-io, x86

I translated the AT&T version of the `toupper.s` from "Programming from the Ground Up" to intel assembly as an exercise. The problem is I get not compile or execution errors (exit code 0) but I still can't manage to see the files being created.

Any inputs? Did I miss translate something? I also implemented some argument verifications but

```
section .data
SYS_OPEN equ 5
SYS_WRITE equ 4
SYS_READ equ 3
SYS_CLOSE equ 6
SYS_EXIT equ 1

O_RDONLY equ 0
O_CREAT_WRONLY_TRUNC equ 3101o

STDIN equ 0
STDOUT equ 1
STDERR equ 2

LINUX_SYSCALL equ 80h
END_OF_FILE equ 0
NUMBER_ARGUMENTS equ 2

section .bss
BUFFER_SIZE equ 700000
BUFFER_DATA resb BUFFER_SIZE

section .text
ST_SIZE_RESERVE equ 8
ST_FD_IN equ -4
ST_FD_OUT equ -8
ST_ARGC equ 0
ST_ARGV_0 equ 4
ST_ARGV_1 equ 8
ST_ARGV_2 equ 12
global _start       ;must be declared for using gcc
_start:                 ;tell linker entry point
mov ebp,esp
sub esp,ST_SIZE_RESERVE

open_files:
open_fd_in:
mov eax,[ebp+ST_ARGC]
cmp eax,2
jl use_system_files_in
jmp use_argc_files_in

use_system_files_in:
mov ebx,STDIN
use_argc_files_in:  
mov ebx,[ebp+ST_ARGV_1]

mov eax,SYS_OPEN
mov ecx,O_RDONLY
mov edx,666o
int LINUX_SYSCALL

cmp eax,0
jl error

store_fd_in:
mov [ebp+ST_FD_IN],eax

open_fd_out:
mov eax,[ebp+ST_ARGC]
cmp eax,2
jl use_system_files_out
jmp use_argc_files_out

use_system_files_out:
mov ebx,STDOUT
use_argc_files_out:  
mov ebx,[ebp+ST_ARGV_2]  

mov eax,SYS_OPEN
mov ebx,STDOUT
mov ecx,O_CREAT_WRONLY_TRUNC
mov edx,666o
int LINUX_SYSCALL
store_fd_out:
mov [ebp+ST_FD_OUT],eax

read_data_loop_begin:
mov eax,SYS_READ
mov ebx,[ebp+ST_FD_IN]
mov ecx,BUFFER_DATA
mov edx,BUFFER_SIZE
int LINUX_SYSCALL

cmp eax,END_OF_FILE
jle read_data_loop_end

read_data_loop_continue:
push BUFFER_DATA
push eax
call convert_to_upper
pop eax
add esp,4

mov edx,eax
mov eax,SYS_WRITE
mov ebx,[ebp+ST_FD_OUT]
mov ecx,BUFFER_DATA
int LINUX_SYSCALL

jmp read_data_loop_begin

read_data_loop_end:
mov eax,SYS_CLOSE
mov ebx,[ebp+ST_FD_OUT] 
int LINUX_SYSCALL

mov eax,SYS_CLOSE
mov ebx,[ebp+ST_FD_IN] 
int LINUX_SYSCALL

mov eax,SYS_EXIT
mov ebx,0
int LINUX_SYSCALL
error:
mov ebx,eax
mov eax,SYS_EXIT
int LINUX_SYSCALL

; ##############################
; Function convert_to_upper
; ##############################
LOWERCASE_A equ 'a'
LOWERCASE_Z equ  'z'
UPPER_CONVERSION equ 'A' - 'a'

ST_BUFFER_LEN equ 8
ST_BUFFER equ 12 

convert_to_upper:
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
mov eax,[ebp+ST_BUFFER]
mov ebx,[ebp+ST_BUFFER_LEN]
mov edi,0

cmp edx,0
je end_convert_loop

convert_loop:
mov cl,[eax+edi*1]

cmp cl,LOWERCASE_A
jl next_byte
cmp cl,LOWERCASE_Z
jg next_byte

add cl,UPPER_CONVERSION
mov [eax+edi*1],cl

next_byte:
inc edi
cmp ebx,edi
jne convert_loop

end_convert_loop:
mov esp,ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

Comment: In `use_argc_files_out` you still have `mov ebx, STDOUT` which overwrites the argument you loaded. Probably just a copy-paste error. Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Besides the already mentioned debugger, strace is also a good tool in these cases.